# What are some examples where the Catalan numbers show up in algorithms/data structures?

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, combinatorics

For some variants of RMQ data structures, the number of Cartesian trees (i.e. the Catalan numbers) is a part of the running-time analysis. What are some other examples where the Cataln numbers show up (either in a data structure itself or in a run-time analysis)?

Comment: [Applications in combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) - you will find an algorithmic problem for the most of this applications..